# Closure in array types

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] {1,2};
Consumer<Integer> lm1 = a -> {
    arr[1] = a; // accepted without any problem
    System.out.println(arr[1]);
};

lm1.accept(100);
```

But compiler has problems with this:

```
Integer b = 10;
Consumer<Integer> lm2 = a -> {
    b = a; // compiler complains
    System.out.println(b);
};

lm2.accept(20);
```

I understand that if I re-initialize `arr` with `new Integer[]{1}` in snippet 1 will cause an error, but I am more interested in understanding why snippet 1 did not cause any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the number of levels of indirection:

- The first example closes over an array, which remains unchanged when you assign: `arr` is fixed, `arr[1]` is not
- The second example closes over an `Integer` object, which you try to change in an assignment `b=a`. This is not allowed.

Note that this behavior is not array-specific: any mutable object can be used to achieve indirection. For example, you could use `AtomicInteger`, which is settable:

```
AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(10);
Consumer<Integer> lm2 = a -> {
    b.set(a); // compiler complains
    System.out.println(b);
};
lm2.accept(20);
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes. The compiler must insist on this, because the original variable itself, such as `b` in your first example, may be gone before the closure is used. For example, consider what would happen if you returned `lm2` from your method.

Comment: Okay, I thought you left that's why I deleted the comment. The comment was ***Compiler is concerned that the reference should be unchanged and not the members of object, right?***. For future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Java lambdas require that any variables you reference within the lambda must be *effectively final* -- that is, you can't modify the value the variable holds.

When you create just a plain `Integer`, it is a regular value type (auto boxing aside) -- assigning to it changes that value and is not allowed.

However, when you wrap the `Integer` in an array, you're not modifying the contents of the variable itself since it's a reference to the array -- you're modifying the array it's referencing.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why did someone downvote it?!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the thing is that Integer is an Object reference and its reference can be changed.

When you have an Array in the other hand it is an fixed set of addresses in the memory, which can't be changed (That's why arrays are fixed-length). So you can only change the value in an array and not its reference.

And the lambda will be invoked at a later time so the compiler wants you to make it final to ensure that you don't change the reference to it.